# SQL display data which is not mapped in another table

Tags: sql, oracle

I am looking for a query to a result where I can see only `userid1` data whose provider is not mapped in `Table 2`; Here is my table definition and data;

```
Table 1

userid  providerid 
1         101    
1         104    
1         106  
1         107
2         102 
2         103
2         104

Table 2

providerid 
101
102
103
104
105
106
107
108
109
110
```

query required as per the  o/p:-

```
userid    providernotavailable
1         102
1         103
1         105
1         108
1         109
1         110
2         101
2         105
2         106
2         107
2         108
2         109
2         110
```

Comment: Select A.Userid,B.Providerid ,  From Table1 A Right Outer Join
Table2 B 
On A.Providerid =B.Providerid 
And A.Userid=1;

Comment: The above query give  o/p of userid 1 ie usermapped to provider as well as not mapped .but for other userid is desired o/p is not coming.

Comment: According to the data given, you will not get any userid in table1 whose providerid doenst match in table2 because all the providerid are present in table2 . The output you have given in the question, is it the query returned output or the output you are looking for ?

Please post , what output you are looking for

Comment: @anudeepks i want query of given output

Comment: Why do you want a stored procedure?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT a.userid, b.providerid FROM table1 a, table2 b
WHERE a.providerid IS NOT NULL
MINUS
SELECT userid, providerid FROM table1 a
WHERE a.providerid IS NOT NULL;
```

The query bring the desired output...
Thanks all for ur efforts.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `not in` operator:

```
SELECT *
FROM   table1
WHERE  providerid NOT IN (SELECT providerid FROM table2)
```

Comment: @NancyGuruswamy Can you elaborate?

Answer (score 0):

Multiple versions: fist with `NOT IN`

```
SELECT table1.*
  FROM table1
 WHERE table1.providerId NOT IN ( SELECT table2.providerId FROM table2 )
```

Second with `NOT EXISTS`:

```
SELECT table1.*
  FROM table1
 WHERE NOT EXISTS ( SELECT 1
                      FROM table2
                     WHERE table1.providerId = table2.providerId )
```

This next one is a bit strange: we do a `LEFT JOIN` and we check that the second table hasn't matched:

```
SELECT table1.*
  FROM table1
       LEFT JOIN table2
       ON table1.providerId = table2.providerId
 WHERE table2.providerId IS NULL
```

Which of the three versions above performs better depends (mostly) on the cardinality of the two tables.

Comment: I want query for the output given  above

Comment: I misunderstood the question. I'll add another answer.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, I misunderstood the question. This should do the trick.
The first part of the query selects all the pairs `userId` - `providerId`. The second part removes all the ones present in `table1`.

```
SELECT U.userId, P.providerId
  FROM (SELECT DISTINCT table1.userId FROM table1) U, table2 P
 MINUS
SELECT table1.* FROM table1
```

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT**

this is the table structure i have used to get the output

```
SQL> desc tab1
 Name                         Null?    Type
 ---------------------------- -------- ----------------
 USERID                                NUMBER(38)
 PROVIDERID                            NUMBER(38)

SQL> desc tab2
 Name                         Null?    Type
 ---------------------------- -------- ----------------
 PROVIDERID                            NUMBER(38)


    SQL>   select distinct(a.userid),b.providerId from tab1 a, tab2 b
     minus
     select  * from tab1 ;

    USERID PROVIDERID
---------- ----------
         1        102
         1        103
         1        105
         1        108
         1        109
         1        110
         2        101
         2        105
         2        106
         2        107
         2        108
         2        109
         2        110

13 rows selected.
```

Comment: ORA-01789: query block has incorrect number of result columns
01789. 00000 -  "query block has incorrect number of result columns"

Comment: are there only 2 columns in the table ? in the tab1 and tab2 columns i just have the columns that you have mentioned in the question above . If you tables have addtional columns please update the question with the structure of both tables

Comment: in table1 there are 2 columns and in table2 there are 1 column.  In query u have mention in select one is distinct(a.userid),b.providerId and other one is select * offcourse it give error.It say incorrect number of result columns.